# Vue.js: Dynamically get registered components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Here's a jsBin showing my scenario](http://jsbin.com/rekudaliho/edit?html,js,output)

I have a selector `<component :is="selectedComponent"></component>`, and a `<select v-model="currentComponent">...</select>` which allows me to select which one is shown.

Currently I am maintaining a separate list of components that looks like so:

```
var componentList = [
  { name: 'Component A', id: 'component-a' },
  { name: 'Component B', id: 'component-b' }
];
```

And that list is fed into the `select` element's `<option>` items with `id` as the value, and `name` as the text.

This is not very DRY as I need to maintain this list with each new component. I would like to abstract the component list in a way that is more elegant.

I tried doing in the app:

```
var vm = Vue.extend({
  components: {
    'component-a': ComponentA,
    // etc.
  }
  computed: {
    componentList: function() {
      // map this.$options.components or something else?
    }
  }
});
```

But I am getting nowhere. Any tips? Best practices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in my current project, I have all my components in a folder called 'components' and inside that folder, an index.js file that exports all the components, like this:

```
export component1 from './component1.vue'
export component2 from './component2.vue'
```

...etc

and inside my vue component I import them all like this:

```
import * as components from '../components'

var vm = new Vue({
  components: components,
  computed: {
    componentsList() {
       return Object.keys(components)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: In your case, how would you manage a "human readable name" for each component?

Comment: In this case, the componentsList computed property returns an array of the component names as defined in my exports file, so in this example it would be ['component1', 'component2']. So in the exports file you would give it a human readable name of your choice